# Tag merge: [sequence] and [series]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Can we merge [series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series) (2 questions) with [sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) (12)? Because we don't really need both of 'em.

Answer (score 3):

**[series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series) and [sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) are not synonyms.** (Whether we actually need the [series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series) tag is another matter, since the only question that uses it correctly was closed as off-topic.)

The [series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series) tag is used for the mathematical definition of a series: the sum of the terms of a sequence. [The first question to use the tag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36889/) does not fit under the sequence tags ([sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence) or [number-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-sequence)) because it is not about finding the rule or next term for a sequence; instead, it is about an upper bound for the sum of the sequence. I think [the other question with the series tag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37620/difficult-sequence) is probably mistagged.

Answer (score -1):

Unless, of course, we decide to implement [series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series) for series' of questions, such as [my clues series.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37784/i-am-an-expression-of-a-deer-mint-clue-one)

Comment: Using the tag for all questions that are part of a series would make it a meta-tag (bad), while [tags for each series](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/) have also been rejected.